# Why is only my last object added to the array?

Tags: swift

So, I have a class ***`Stand`*** which has an `array` of type **`Bike`**. 
I create a few object of class `Stand` and then I want to add a few bikes to the `array` of type `Bike`. Every stand should have a different number of bikes in this list.

Then I have to show the list of stands on a `mapView`, where the the number of bikes for every stand is shown.

***My Problem*** is that when I add for example, I have 3 stands, only the bikes for the last stand are shown in number of bikes per stand.

So, if stand 1 has 2 bikes, stand 2 has 1 bike and stand bike has 3 bikes - all stands will show that they have 3 bikes.

In other words, for some reason only the last object is added to the list. How can I fix that?

It is pretty much hardcoded for now. 
Here is my code:

```
var stands = [Stand] ()
var stand101 = Stand(id:101, nrOfSpots:15,latitude:51.4516,longtitude:5.4697)
var stand102 = Stand(id:102, nrOfSpots:15,latitude:51.4616,longtitude:5.4997)
var stand103 = Stand(id:103, nrOfSpots:15,latitude:51.4345,longtitude:5.4397)

stand101.addBikeToStand(bike:Bike(id:1,name:"BikeToHeaven",latitude:51.4416,longtitude:5.4697,available:true))
stand101.addBikeToStand(bike:Bike(id:2,name:"BikeToHell",latitude:51.4616,longtitude:5.4997,available:true))
stands.append(stand101)

stand102.addBikeToStand(bike:Bike(id:3,name:"BikeToBulgaria",latitude:51.4345,longtitude:5.4397,available:true))
stands.append(stand102)
stand103.addBikeToStand(bike:Bike(id:4,name:"Sparta",latitude:51.4316,longtitude:5.4697,available:false))
stand103.addBikeToStand(bike:Bike(id:5,name:"Athene",latitude:51.4116,longtitude:5.4997,available:true))
stands.append(stand103)
```

**EDIT**

```
// How bikes are shown
for s in fietshare.stands {
   lbAvailable.text = "Available Bikes: " + String(s.bikes.count) 
   nrOfAvailable.text =  String(b.distance) + "M"
}
```

Comment: The code you’ve shown has nothing to do with the problem you’ve described. Show the code that _displays_ the info.

Comment: I have edited it now.

Comment: Still nothing that explains your issue, I think the problem is in the `Stand` class

Comment: What is "fietshare"? Is "Stand" a Class or a Struct (you may give detail of this Type in your post)? Is "bikes" a list, how it is implemented and filled? You should add more detail.

Comment: Well, the stand class pretty much has a few properties such as id, location and etc. Also, the bikes arrayList is there. When I print the bikes.count in the console it shows the proper number per stand but not on the map where I get only the number of the last stand.

Comment: So the problem lies between the code you have shown us and the map in the UI?

Comment: So the problem is how you update your UI according to your class instance, provide the code where you update the UI. Note that the code you provided in your EDIT is a for-loop that override the text in "lbAvailable" and "nrOfAvailable" at each iteration.

Comment: @LouisLac I didn't read that last code careful enough. This is probably the solution to the issue or a part of it at least

Comment: The thing is, when now you say it, I think I am not updating the UI. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop

```
// How bikes are shown
for s in fietshare.stands {
   lbAvailable.text = "Available Bikes: " + String(s.bikes.count) 
   nrOfAvailable.text =  String(b.distance) + "M"
}
```

you are iterating through stands array and showing the number of available bikes, the problem here is your label will always show the number of bikes in the last object.

To overcome this problem you have to make a number of labels equal to number of stands

```
fietshare.stands.forEach { s in 
let lbAvailable = UILabel()
let nrOfAvailable = UILabel()

  lbAvailable.text = "Available Bikes: " + String(s.bikes.count) 
  nrOfAvailable.text =  String(b.distance) + "M"
}
```

Comment: How do I access s and b here If I don't use the for loop anymore?

Comment: Hm, it seems to  work though, I have annotations pop ups equal to the number of stands and now in every pop up of annotation it shows the number of bikes for every stand in the same pop up.  Like this : https://ibb.co/MghNPsX